# InternalError: too much recursion - getting in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a aspx page that takes along time to post due to toomany codes and db connection. That is not a problem. I need to disable the post button when the user clicks it which I am able to do. The second thing that I want to accomplish is to change the button value to Please Wait .... To accomplish this I am using settime out so that after every 1 second a dot is appended to it. But when I run the code I get InternalError: too much recursion?

Please help My code is as follows.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return disable();" />
```

**JS**

```
var m = "Please Wait";

function disable() {
    try {
        $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        setTimeout(showmsg(), 5000);
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
    return true;
}

function showmsg() {
    if (m.length > 15) {
        m = "Please Wait";
    }
    m = m + ".";
    $("<%=Button1.ClientID %>").val(m);
    setTimeout(showmsg(), 1000);
}
```

Comment: It should be `setTimeout(showmsg, 1000);` and not `setTimeout(showmsg(), 1000);` - `setTimeout()` expects a function (or JS in a string) as the argument, not the function return value (unless the return value is a function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing showmsg as a function but you are executing it!
Replace every

setTimeout(**showmsg()**,....) 
to

setTimeout(**showmsg**,.....)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
setTimeout(showmsg, 5000);
```

and let me know